# Angular directive in ng-repeat, $http.get re-runs on filter

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, directive

Using ng-repeat on a directive to display a collection of customer photos from an array of customer objects. The directive takes a customer id and makes an $http.get request to an api that returns the image data. I also have a search input to filter the displayed customer objects. Every time I start to clear the search input and more items return to the view, angular makes the $http.get request again for each instance of the directive and re downloads the image data. How do I avoid this? Thanks!

HTML:

```
  <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            <contact-photo ng-repeat="customer in customers.customerList | filter:customers.search" id="customer.id" />
        </div>
  </div>
```

Controller:

```
function Customers($http) {
    var vm = this;

    $http.get('/api/customers')
       .then(function (response) {
           vm.customerList = response.data;
       });
};
```

Directive:

```
function contactPhoto() {
    return {
        scope: {},
        bindToController: {
            id: '='
        },
        templateUrl: 'app/common/contactPhoto.vbhtml',
        controller: function ($http, $scope) {
            var vm = this;

            //vm.imgSrc
            $scope.$watch('vm.id', function (newval, oldval) {
                if (newval) {
                    $http.get('/api/Customers/' + vm.id + '/photo?shape=square')
                        .then(function (response) {
                            if (response.data != null) {
                                vm.imgSrc = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + response.data;
                            } else {
                                vm.imgSrc = "content/img/DefaultUser.png"
                            }
                        });
                }
            });
        },
        controllerAs: 'vm'
    };
}
```

UPDATE 1:

I changed my directive controller to remove the $watch on the variable in question. I still get the same problem, where it re-runs on every filter.

```
function contactPhoto() {
    return {
        scope: {},
        bindToController: {
            id: '='
        },
        templateUrl: 'app/common/contactPhoto.vbhtml',
        controller: function ($http, $scope, $timeout) {
            var vm = this;

            //vm.imgSrc
            $timeout(function () {
                $http.get('/api/Customers/' + vm.id + '/photo?shape=square')
                    .then(function (response) {
                        if (response.data != null) {
                            vm.imgSrc = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + response.data;
                        } else {
                            vm.imgSrc = "content/img/DefaultUser.png"
                        }
                });
            })
        },
        controllerAs: 'vm'
    };
}
```

Comment: You have put watch for vm.id, so obviously it will call $http.get for any change. I hope you understood!

Comment: Originally I was just running $http.get in the directive controller without the watch function around it. But I was having trouble because vm.id was always 'undefined'. I read elsewhere that it had to do with digest cycles, and one technique was to $watch the variable for an initial change.

But, even with the watch, when I filter the source array, then un-filter, is that vm.id changing?

Comment: I changed my directive controller to remove the $watch on the variable in question. I still get the same problem, where it re-runs on every filter.